# How to get the data inside the Push.Key Firebase for Android Kotlin

Tags: android, json, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

i wanted to show the data based user input to textView. But somehow after i check the result through Println it only show me "com.google.firebase.database.Query@cd46e75".

my Code :
[image]

and my JSON Structure in Firebase : [image]

Comment: Make sure you post your code as text instead of images.

Comment: the `.orderByChild` is questionable as that needs to be one of the properties you want to sort by; agama, gender, name etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code merely defines a query. It doesn't yet execute that query, nor read the matching data from the database.

To do that, use a listener like this:

```
query.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        for (userSnapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
            viewData.setText(userSnapshot.child("name").getValue<String>())
        }
    }

    override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
        Log.w(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException())
    }
})
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [reading data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events).

Comment: Hello thx for the asnwer. But when i tried to run with ur code, it gave me error on "getValue<String>()" with error message "No type arguments expected for fun getValue(): Any?"

Comment: You might not have imported the Kotlin extensions for Firebase. In that case you can also do `getValue(String::class)`.